# Add a header to an array so the header becomes incorporated with the array

Tags: php

I am using this code to create an xlsx file:

[class file here](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen/blob/master/src/SimpleXLSXGen.php)

```
include("xl.php");
$books = array();

$sql="SELECT filename, last_name from banker_be WHERE disburse_dt ='09/22/2020'";
$result=mysqli_query ($dbc,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
array_push($books, $row);
}
 
$xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $books );
$xlsx->downloadAs('books.xlsx');
```

This results in an xlsx file with all the columns and rows from the table

What is missing is the header column for the xlsx file

I have tried inserting it this way:

```
$head = "['ID, 'Name']";
$xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $head . $books );
$xlsx->downloadAs('books.xlsx');
```

How can I insert a header above the array and have it read as the first row in the xlsx file?

Comment: Push a proper array to $books, before you add the rows?  You can't just concat arrays like strings (though $head in your code is a string).

Comment: The array data comes from a MySQL table - no headers in the first row - I am open to ideas how to get the header - ie "ID, Name" into the array so it will get into the xlsx file

Comment: I gave you the idea above, push your headers into the array.  Or start the array seeded with your headers.

Comment: When I said push, a meant array_push.  As you already had used that in your code.  array_merge just isn't needed here.  That's why it wasn't suggested.  It's pricier because it re-indexes.  But whatever suits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, and this is nice code if you want to export to an xlsx file (not just xls) - and save the class file noted above, save as anything you want ( *.php) and include it in your file - (spare you the pain of trying to figure out how to install composer, or the 'project' via composer to a shared host - like godaddy):

```
 <?

 $fnd = array();
 include("xl.php"); // <-- the class file
 $sql="SELECT filename,last_name from table";
 $result=mysqli_query ($dbc,$sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
 array_push($fnd, $row);
 }
 
 $hd1 = [['Filename','Borr Last Name']];
 $arm = array_merge($hd1, $fnd);
 $xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $arm );
 $xlsx->downloadAs('books.xlsx');

 ?>
```

So, the secret sauce in this deal was **array_merge**

Comment: Or just start with `$arm = [['Filename','Borr Last Name']];`; and then in your loop: `$arm[] = $row;`.  Saves the merge.  Manual: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.